# Read date values from a JSON file into Java HashMap

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
    "calendar": {
        "dateToDayId": {
            "2016-07-14": 290356,
            "2016-08-26": 380486,
            "2016-09-07": 417244,
            "2016-08-15": 354271,
            "2016-07-25": 311762
        },
        "dishIdToMealId": {
            "1228578": 474602,
            "1228585": 474602,
            "1228586": 474602,
        ...... // more fields
}
```

I'm trying to read the `<date, number>` pairs under `dateToDayId` into a `HashMap<Date, Long>` in java. First I created a `JsonInfo` class which holds a `Calendar` class object. The `Calendar` class object in turns holds all the classes including `DateToDayId`, `DishToMealId` and so on. My `DateToDayId` class looks like this (I'm using `Jackson` to parse JSON file):

```
package jsonfields;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import deserializers.CustomDateDeserializer;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class DateToDayId {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
    private TreeMap <Date, Long> dateToDayMappings;

    public TreeMap<Date, Long> getDateToDayMappings() {
        return dateToDayMappings;
    }

    public void setDateToDayMappings(TreeMap<Date, Long> dateToDayMappings) {
        this.dateToDayMappings = dateToDayMappings;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DateToDayId{" +
                "dateToDayMappings=" + dateToDayMappings +
                '}';
    }
}
```

My `Main` class looks like this:

```
import java.io.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("path\\to\\file\\test.json"));
            JsonInfo jsonInfo = objectMapper.readValue(inputStreamReader, JsonInfo.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "2016-07-14" (class jsonfields.DateToDayId), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "dateToDayMappings"])
 at [Source: (InputStreamReader); line: 1, column: 48] (through reference chain: JsonInfo["calendar"]->jsonfields.Calendar["dateToDayId"]->jsonfields.DateToDayId["2016-07-14"])
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class mapping is wrong. You need to have map with variable name `dateToDayId` in `Calendar`. Below modified code should work for your need.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class JSONMapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\ws\\test\\test.json"));
            JsonInfo jsonInfo = objectMapper.readValue(inputStreamReader, JsonInfo.class);
            System.out.println(jsonInfo);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class JsonInfo{
    Calendar calendar;

    public Calendar getCalendar() {
        return calendar;
    }

    public void setCalendar(Calendar calendar) {
        this.calendar = calendar;
    }
}

class Calendar {
    private TreeMap <Date, Long> dateToDayId;

    public TreeMap<Date, Long> getDateToDayId() {
        return dateToDayId;
    }

    public void setDateToDayId(TreeMap<Date, Long> dateToDayId) {
        this.dateToDayId = dateToDayId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DateToDayId{" +
                "dateToDayMappings=" + dateToDayId +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: If I run the modified code, I get this error: ``java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "{" (through reference chain: JsonInfo["calendar"]->jsonfields.Calendar["dateToDayId"])``

Comment: Are you getting error after adding CustomDateDeserializer or without that ?